# How to format date in AngularJS when posting data to a REST end point

Tags: javascript, spring, date, angularjs, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC REST backend application. I'm sending the date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format to the client.

But if I format the date in "mm/dd/yyyy" and POST it back, data binding fails.

Here is my Spring customdateserializer obj that converts java.util.date to mm/dd/yyy when sending the date to the frontend

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {  
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider arg2) throws 
        IOException, JsonProcessingException {      

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(value);

        gen.writeString(formattedDate);

    }
}
```

Here is the object for which data binding fails

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bill")
public class Bill implements GenericObject {

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date billDate;

    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
    public Date getBillDate() {
        return billDate;
    }

    public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
        this.billDate = billDate;
    }
}
```

Here is the end point to which I'm posting the data (Spring MVC controller)

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/user/{userId}/bill" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public void addBill(@RequestBody Bill bill_p,@PathVariable("userId") int userId,
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse_p, WebRequest request_p) {

        processing......

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can say is that do not send formatted date to the browser. Send the `Date` type structure\object let the date formatting be handled on the client side. Angular has a `date` filter for this task.

Similarly for sending data to server, do not send any formatted data but the model date value and i believe the server side deserializer would handle it. See the format being send on the wire for your request.

Comment: Should I send the date from Spring to Angular as is without my customdateserializer?

Comment: Thanks. Used the angular filter to display it properly {{ date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}. Now trying to figure out how to use Bootstrap datepicker and package the date properly.